# Will this Perl program work on Windows?

Tags: perl

I am trying to open multiple processes in a Perl script on Windows. Program structure would look some thing like this...

```
 my($chld1_out, $chld1_in);
   my($chld2_out, $chld2_in);
   my($chld3_out, $chld3_in);
   my @cmds1=();
   my @cmds2=();
   my @cmds3=();

    $pid1 = open2($chld1_out, $chld1_in, 'ex1.exe')or die $!;
    $pid2 = open2($chld2_out, $chld2_in, 'ex2.pl')or die $!;
    $pid3 = open2($chld3_out, $chld3_in, 'ex3.exe')or die $!;

   print $chld1_in $cmds1[0];
   print $chld2_in $cmds2[0];
   $op1=<$chld1_out>;
   $op2=<$chld2_out>;
   if ( $op1 == 'done' && $op1 != 'done')
   print $chld1_in $cmds1[0];
   elsif ( $op1 != 'done' && $op1 == 'done')
   print $chld2_in $cmds2[0];
   elsif ( $op1 == 'done' && $op1 == 'done')
   print $chld1_in $cmds1[1];
   print $chld2_in $cmds2[1];
   .....
   .....
   for loops and while loops..... to process with the data output... and do conditional programming. 
   close $pid1 or die $!;
    close $pid2 or die $!;
    close $pid3 or die $!;
```

If it does how can I execute the Perl script ( ex2.pl )
one way i know is 
system($^X,"ex2.pl","arg") ;

I would appreciate fro your help on this ASAP...

Thanks,

-Abishek

Comment: This code is screaming for a refactor... why aren't you use a subroutine here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not, "opening" a process for reading is usually a fork and a pipe behind the scenes. And fork-execs don't work on Windows*.

For executing a *Perl* script, just [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html#do-EXPR) it.

```
do 'ex2.pl';
```

And if you want to pass args:

```
{   local @ARGV = qw<One Two Three>;
    do 'ex2.pl';
}
```

When `ex2.pl` wants to access `@ARGV` it will be `( 'One', 'Two', 'Three' )`. Of course if you want to do any of the perl shorthand `ARGV` tricks, it's better to localize the GLOB.

```
{ local *ARGV = [ qw<One Two Three> ]; ... }
```

* - I've long thought that a suitable workaround *should* be possible using Windows process structures which have a readable stdout and stderr, as a well as a writable stdin.

Comment: I would be really helpful if you can point me the workaround solution.. interaction btw ex1.exe and ex3.exe would be really great.

Comment: so you mean if i install strawberry perl the above mentioned program will work ??????

Comment: Strawberry Perl has a trick to implement forks under windows. I'm not sure how it works, it may be threads, or some magical windows feature abuse. But it does work for the most part.

Comment: Kent: It's using ithreads and it is NOT specific to Strawberry Perl. It's part of the core and was (IIRC) originally put together by the nice folks at ActiveState.